# Trying to undo some commands

Tags: sudo, ram, delete

I have done the following commands trying to make Ubuntu work faster:

```
echo 100 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_ratio
echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory

#/etc/sysctl.conf прописываем:
vm.overcommit_memory=2
vm.overcommit_ratio=100
```

It's become worse. I want to "undo" those commands. So deleted these 2 lines from `/etc/sysctl.conf` but I can't neither change no delete the first two files, it says "permission denied" even when I say "sudo su" or just "sudo".

Comment: What is the exact command you use?

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad, "sudo rm  /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_ratio"

Comment: I think to reboot is enough, because first 2 files are located on VFS and probably depend on configuration parameters. However, I may be wrong suggesting this. If so, I will be glad if somebody reveal my misconception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ echo 50 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_ratio 
50
$ echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory 
0
```

This will revert those files to the default parameters. Notice that you **can not** delete them because they are virtual and your system relies on that they are persist.

Comment: @gertvdijk, thanks! I forgot the right redirection symbol :)